# Callbacks in java

Tags: java, concurrency, callback

Is it possible to implement a callback functionality in java. The executor service or Future Apis in java are only close to it but is not really a callback IMO. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Why exactly do you think Java doesn't support callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks in Java have been traditionally done with interfaces (for instance Runnable and Callable). Java 8 has introduced Lambda expressionss which alter the syntax of callbacks, but not the underlying mechanics (as far as I understand them). Note that *anything* that uses the observer pattern is essentially using a callback structure, including ActionListeners, PropertyChangeListeners, etc. And these are often based on passing interface implementations (or now lambda expressions) into method parameters.

Comment: Yes you are right that anything that uses observer pattern is essentially a callback. But may be I've not been clear enough asking the question. My doubt is does java support callback mechanism in case of remote communication similar to ajax in javascript.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html support callbacks of type http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html for network communications.